# SQL Server Conditional Join instead of WHERE .. IN .. clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

```
SELECT A.Name, H.Name as BookedBy
 FROM dbo.vwAllLoads A WITH (NOEXPAND) 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.SystemInfo H 
     ON (A.BookedByUserID = H.GlobalNetUserID) 
 WHERE ((A.CustomerID IN (SELECT UCR.CustomerID
                             FROM dbo.UserCustomerRelations UCR  
                             WHERE UCR.UserID IN 
                                       (SELECT UserID FROM @PodUsers) 
                                OR H.GlobalUserID IN 
                                       (SELECT UserID FROM @PodUsers)))
```

Now I filter data using above where clause. How can I accomplish the same using joins or in a better way?

Please help

Comment: Can you please share you entire query?

Comment: What is `A`?  What is `H`?

Comment: H is not defined.  Can assume A is a table.

Comment: Entire query included, please help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query is something like:

```
select a.*
from a
where A.CustomerID IN (SELECT UCR.CustomerID 
                       FROM dbo.UserCustomerRelations UCR
                       WHERE UCR.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM @PodUsers) OR
                             UCR.GlobalNetUserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM @PodUsers)
-----------------------------^ was `H`, I'm assuming is `UCR`
                      )
```

Then the following should be an equivalent query using `join`s:

```
select distinct a.*
from a join
     dbo.UserCustomerRelations ucr
     on A.CustomerID = ucr.CustomerID join
     @PodUsers pu
     on ucr.UserId = pu.UserId or ucr.UserId = ucr.GlobalNetUserID = pu.UserId;
```

The `distinct` would be unnecessary if you know that the joins do not produce multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserCustomerRelations] UCR
    ON A.[CustomerID] = UCR.[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN @PodUsers PU
    ON UCR.[CustomerID] = PD.[UserID]
    OR H.[GlobalNetUserID] = PD.[UserID]
```